# Start a program on remote computer without any third party software

Tags: windows, networking, process, wmi

I'm trying to find a way to start a program on a remote computer (in a domain environment, so I know all the credentials) without any third-party software like PSExec.

Now the problem is, that it should run interactively! (And in the best case, it should run in the current logged-in user context) I know WMI, and I know that you can start a process with WMI but it's not interactive. (You can start an interactive process with a scheduled task but then it runs as a system process and has system privileges(?))

Now lets say I want to write a C# application for the IT technicians to supervise the systems, do you have any idea which technique can be used to allow the IT technicians to start programs remotely without installing software?

Or, in other words, is there something else other than WMI-scheduled processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps program yourself what PSExec does, if this is a solution for you. If I remember well about how PSExec works, it begins by copying the file to run on the remote system using the admin shares (e.g., \\PCNAME\ADMIN$\TEMP; if necessary, you can connect to the remote computer with the right credentials using the `WNetAddConnection2()` function). If the file you copy on the remote machine can be run as a system service (which can be the case, if you write one), you can use `OpenSCManager()`, `CreateService()` and `StartService()` to start it. Services can run in interactive mode (see the `SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS` flag, which requires the service to run as the system account). The service can then impersonate the logged-on user, perhaps by using `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()` using a token obtained from one of his running processes with `OpenProcessToken()`, but I never tried to see if this works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Input :)
And you really think that PSExec copys the file to the remote host?

Comment: Yes, it does copy the file to the remote host if you specify the -c option (see help text of psexec). If not, "the application must be in the system path on the remote system.".